# Recovering Cyanogenmod (no context found)

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

I was using my phone, battery was low and it suddenly shut down. I thought it's because of battery, and plugged in my charger. Now i'm trying to boot my phone but it's stucking at CYANOGENMOD boot screen:

[image: CM10 boot screen]
<sup>Here I'm stuck (click for larger image)</sup>

Reboot my phone with CWM Recovery mod, and i'm getting **no context found** error.

I don't know what it's mean and how can i deal with this problem.

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S2 and CWM v6.0.3.3 . I'm not sure how can i find my Cyanogenmod version.

** UPDATE **
I've wait for a long time on boot screen and now "Android is updating" screen appeared. It's optimized my all apps and now and waiting on starting apps message for 8 hours. It stuck at starting apps screen.

Comment: Which device are you using? Which versions of Cyanogenmod and CWM are you using?

Comment: @dotVezz just added.

Comment: @eray if that is the answer, post it as one.

Comment: @JeffreyLin if you mean that update message, no it's stuck at "starting apps" screen for 8 hours.

Comment: Its stuck there? Did you try taking the battery out and putting it back in?

Comment: @JeffreyLin yes i've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try clearing cache and rebooting if you are able to get inside CWM